# Flutter: SDK location cannot be moved or changed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have mistakenly installed flutter SDK on C:\ProgramFiles and whenever I  go inside VS code it says Flutter SDK is installed in a protected folder and might not function. I cannot seem to uninstall the SDK nor move it to another file, it says the file is open somewhere else. I have deleted the Environment Variable of the flutter SDK and still can't do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever added something to Windows system PATH restart your computer. Moreover close every kind of program that could use the SDK PATH. Just install the SDK once again in default (?) path?

VS Code and and for ex. Android Studio self detect the SDK PATH.

Comment: How stupid of me to not realize that I needed to restart my laptop, thank you it worked now!

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. First, copy the Flutter folder that is placed inside `c:\Program Files`
2. Paste it outside the `c:/Program files`
3. Now delete the Flutter folder which is inside the `c:\Program files`
4. Now open the Flutter folder placed in the `c:\` drive and open the `bin` folder and copy the path
5. Update the path of the Flutter SDK on the environment variable

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve the formatting. Can you verify that my edits are to your expectation? Notably, I also changed `c:/Programfiles` to `c:\Program Files`, which is what I assume you intended?